# How to show update messages in PHP?

Tags: php, authentication

Building a simple login page. If the user types in a password and password confirmation that don't match, I want to reset the registration form and print an message. Currently, the message does not print, but carries on through the script. This is what I've tried, by way of setting a SESSION variable when the error occurs, and showing this variable upon reload:

registration.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['errmsg'])) {
        print($_SESSION['errmsg']);
        unset($_SESSION['errmsg']);
    }
?>

<form name="register" action="register.php" method="post">
    <label>Username</label><input type="text" name="username" maxlength="20" />
    <label>Password</label><input type="password" name="pass" />
    <label>Password Again</label><input type="password" name="pass_confirm" />
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

register.php:

```
<?php
function create_salt() {
    $string = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    return substr($string, 0, 3);
}

session_start();
$username = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$pass_confirm = $_POST['pass_confirm'];

if ($pass != $pass_confirm) {
    $_SESSION['errmsg'] = "Passwords do not match.";
    header('Location: registration.php');
}

if (strlen($username) > 20) {
    header('Location: registration.php');
}

$hash = hash('sha256', $pass);
$salt = create_salt();
$hash = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash);

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'test4', 'test4');
mysql_select_db('test4', $conn);

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);

$query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, salt) VALUES ('$username', '$hash', '$salt');";

mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

The important part is the line `if ($pass != $pass_confirm) { ...`. Currently if the passwords do not match this condition is met, but it will carry on through the script rather than reloading via `header(Location: registration.php)`. I am aware that `header()` cannot be invoked after data has been sent, which is probably causing the problem.

If so, is there a better way to do this in PHP or should I be looking at alternatives?

Comment: Your code should work if you also have `<?php ?>` tags in `register.php` and no other data outside those tags. Do you have error output enabled in PHP? Does this script generate any error?

Comment: Sorry, I ommited those in the above. Edited now. There are php tags in `register.php`, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `die();` or `exit;` solves the problem.

```
header('Location: registration.php');
die();
```

Comment: I don't suppose you know why or if this is a 'healthy' solution? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is a healthy solution. And the header(Location) behavior is expected not to end the script - it just writes to the header. The script continues till you tell it to stop. When the script ends, the header is send to the browser and instructs it to redirect.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to output some data and then possibly choose to redirect, you can use output buffering. This causes the output you've generated to be placed in a buffer instead of being sent to the user.  If you need to redirect, it works because there's no data sent yet.  If you don't redirect, you make use of what's in the buffer and output once the script is done.

See this PHP Manual page to lean *much* more about PHP output buffering:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.outcontrol.php

Also, note that you're calling `header()` twice if you have the error - the second header call with the 'location' type will overwrite the first and send you to index.php.

Please see @talereader's answer above - the key is to determine that you're in the error state and call the header (which you do) and then terminate the script immediately.

Comment: Could you explain further? I'm confused because if the two passwords don't match, `header('Location: registration.php');` isn't invoked and the script continues, even if I take out the session variable code. Why doesn't it want to go back to `registration.php`?

Comment: @talereader has it - your script was setting up the header to redirect to registration.php, but then the script was also redirecting to index.php which was overwriting the first redirect.  `header()` calls replace similar `header()` calls by default unless you specify the second parameter as false.  The bigger idea is that if you want to end your script and kick off another at another address with `header()`, you need to end the current script there with something like `die()`.  Otherwise the first script doesn't know you want it to stop executing.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do all your checking and set a flag if something fails. i.e `$failed = true;` then before you do any actual processing do `if (!$failed) { //process }`.

Comment: So header() can only be invoked at the end of the script?

Comment: No, header can be invoked anywhere, but you can overwrite one header with another. Also, you can have problems with outputting headers if the page output has already started.